# How to interact between Puppeteer and a Chrome extension through the windows.create method?

Tags: puppeteer, metamask

1. Using Puppeteer
   2.[plugin github](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/46a2604df0f09f412c89d586a552ff2d07f9dff0/app/scripts/platforms/extension.js)
2. you can see that the extension opens a new window using the window.create API.
3. I have already tried using `this.browser.on('targetcreated')`.But unable to obtain it
4. 

Being able to obtain this window and use Puppeteer's API normally.